# Deep Learning libraries support on MacPro's AMD graphics?

Tags: mojave, mac-pro, gpu

Ever since Apple and Nvidia had a [fight](https://appleinsider.com/articles/19/01/18/apples-management-doesnt-want-nvidia-support-in-macos-and-thats-a-bad-sign-for-the-mac-pro), apple resorted to AMD for powering up graphics. However, most of the ML/DL libraries support only Nvidia GPUs. Are there any libraries (or hacks) out there which support AMD GPUs right out of the box ?